# Runtime error 800A9C68 while triggering .vbs file from Python to run a macro

Tags: python, vbscript

I ma trying to trigger a VBA macro from python using the below code that uses a .vbs file. However while running it always throws up the error shown below. Any advise would be highly appreciated.

```
os.system(r"C:\\Users\\shashi.singh\\Desktop\\VBA\\HKMA.vbs")
print("Success...")
```

[image]

This is the first time I have faced this error and haven't found any solution yet.

VBScript for reference:

```
curdir = "C:\Users\shashi.singh\Desktop\VBA" 
Set myxlApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
myxlApplication.Visible = False 
Set myworkbook =myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open(curdir & "\HKMA.xlsm")
myworkbook.Application.Run "Module1.Xopy" 
myworkbook.Close False 
myxlApplication.Quit
```

Comment: The error is from your VBScript, so you'll need to show the VBScript code.

Comment: This is the VB sript that I am using. `curdir = "C:\Users\shashi.singh\Desktop\VBA"

Set myxlApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxlApplication.Visible = False
Set myworkbook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open(curdir & "\HKMA.xlsm")
myworkbook.Application.Run "Module1.Xopy"
myworkbook.Close False
myxlApplication.Quit`

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: @Angasar Added the VBScript in my question. Kindly assist.

Comment: You can't put multiple statements in one line without separating them with colons. Please show the code as it is in your script.

Comment: Done Ansgar.. Does this help? This is how the code looks like in my VBScript.

Comment: That would give you a syntax error in line 3. Please copy/paste the actual code that is producing the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179164/discussion-between-shashi-shankar-singh-and-ansgar-wiechers).